# Use function return as the content for a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return

i'd like to use the return value of a specific function as the condition of an if statement. Is that possible ?

I'm basically building a string inside a function that takes an array (the conditionArray) and concatenates it to a statement.
Then it returns this condition as a string.
After that, i wanted to use this string as the condition of my if-statement.

My current problem looks something like that.

```js
var answer = prompt("Tell me the name of a typical domestic animal");

var conditionArray = new Array("Dog", "Turtle", "Cat", "Mouse")

function getCondition(conditionArray) {

  for (i = 0; i < conditionArray.length; i++) {

    if (i != conditionArray.length) {

      condition += 'answer === ' + conditionArray[i] + ' || ';

    } else {

      condition += 'answer === ' + conditionArray[i];

    }

    return condition;


  }

}

if (getCondition(conditionArray)) {

  alert("That is correct !");

} else {

  alert("That is not a domestic animal !");

}
```

Comment: One thing is in your `if` statement you are using an assignment operator (=) rather than an equality operator (==).

Answer (score 0):

For this type of test use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), `x = arr.indexOf(item)`

- `x === -1` means `item` is not in `arr`
- Otherwise `x` is the index of `arr` that the first occurrence of `item` is located

```
var options = ["Dog", "Turtle", "Cat", "Mouse"],
    answer = prompt("Tell me the name of a typical domestic animal");

// some transformation of `answer` here, i.e. casing etc

if (options.indexOf(answer) !== -1) {
    alert("That is correct !");
} else {
  alert("That is not a domestic animal !");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It should solve my current problem. But for the future and further problems. Is there any chance to write a string into the conditional statement as mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this kind of test is to use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). See Paul's answer for more details on how to use it.

--

If you *really* *really* want to return a condition, you can use `eval()` to evaluate the condition string. Keep in mind that `eval()` is dangerous though. It's usage isn't recommended. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval_needlessly!

```
if (eval(getCondition(conditionArray))) {
  alert("That is correct !");
} else {
  alert("That is not a domestic animal !");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation, thats what i was looking for. Nevertheless you're right, its far too dangerous for production :/

Comment: To be clear, there's no other way to evaluate a condition string unless you write a parser yourself. One thing you can do is sanitizing the string before passing it into the eval function.